# How to check if a class is loaded or not in a Java process

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

My task is to find out how many springboot app are running on a Linux system.
So What I am planning to do is,

**1.** to get all the java process IDs

```
$ ps -aux|grep java
```

**2.** Then somehow get the loaded classes from the IDs.

I don't know if it is possible or not. Someone please kind enough to guide me to the right direction? 
**P.S.** : I am using java to run the above command by the help of Process class, something like this :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef");
```

So I want to do it from a java project.

Comment: Don't use the good old `ps ... | grep ....`. In Linux, you can at least use `ps -fC java` to list all processes that execute `java`. Even better would be to use the Oracle JDK's own utility to list Java processes on a system: `jps` .  However, this one lists only processes of the same user.

Comment: @gsl I will look into jps and revert back asap

Answer (score 1):

I came to this page searching for a recipe "how to find if a jar has been loaded" (which is a bit different than the original question). But perhaps it will be useful for somebody:

I found `jcmd` as best way to get this info, for example:

1. I have a running JVM with PID 1 (it's a CN application started in K8s):

```
$ jps 
1 MyAppLauncher
529 Jps
```

2. Figure out what options `jcmd` provides for this JVM:

```
[eceuser@ecs1-0 temp]$ jcmd 1 help
1:
The following commands are available:
JFR.stop
JFR.start
JFR.dump
JFR.check
VM.native_memory
VM.check_commercial_features
VM.unlock_commercial_features
ManagementAgent.stop
ManagementAgent.start_local
ManagementAgent.start
VM.classloader_stats
GC.rotate_log
Thread.print
GC.class_stats
GC.class_histogram
GC.heap_dump
GC.finalizer_info
GC.heap_info
GC.run_finalization
GC.run
VM.uptime
VM.dynlibs
VM.flags
VM.system_properties
VM.command_line
VM.version
help
```

3. With a bit of try and error, I found that `VM.dynlibs` does what I needed:

```
$ jcmd 1 VM.dynlibs | grep custom
7f59a4b3b000-7f59a4b3d000 r--s 00000000 fd:00 1116085962                 /home/app/lib/custom-fi-extensions-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So yes, this jar has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put some sort of identifier into your app's startup command line. E.g. something like:

   ```
   String id = "com.app.demo";
   ```
2. When you run your app, make sure to include the string. Let's say you start it from within Java, do the following:

   ```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\...\javaw.exe -cp ... -Dwhatever=" + id + " com.app.app.demo.Main");
   ```
3. Get the application by `id` like `$ps aux | grep -i com.app.app.demo`. In Java call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux | grep -i com.app.app.demo");`

I would prefer using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead(from Java 8), and running your command via bash:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("bash", "ps aux | grep com.app.app.demo").start()
```

Hope this gives an idea.

Comment: I cannot make any changes on the java projects running as processes. so i cannot add something extra to those processes and re-run them.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty method: some static block into your class and in it print something into a log (or system.out). Static block is executed when class is loaded by class loader and not when the first instance instantiated (this is when constructor is called for the first time). Then if your printout is in the log then the class has been loaded. Example:
`public class Sample {
   private static final Logger logger = ...
   static {
      logger.info("class Sample is loaded");
   }
...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can identify some specific class which determines if the application is a springboot application, you could use some tool from the jdk, which can output loaded classes. I've tried it with jcmd(you'll find it under jre/bin/):

I'm not very good with bash so it might be not very efficient, but this works for me assuming that every springboot application has loaded class `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingInitializationContext` and no non-springboot app loads it.

```
ps aux | grep [j]ava | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} jcmd {} VM.class_hierarchy | grep "org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingInitializationContext"
```

It finds processes containing `java`, takes only the PID, passes it to the jcmd where you grep for the specific class. The output seems to be correct, the only problem is that I loose the PID in this long pipe and I'm not sure how to print it. 
But if your problem is "how many springboot apps", then it might not be an issue. I'm also not sure if the classes may appear twice when using `jcmd VM.class_hierarchy`, but it doesn't look like it.

Note: This works on JDK 11. I tried jmap first, but that doesn't work for me on JDK 11 for some reason.

Comment: jcmd might help me out, I will try it and revert back asap... thanks